# How to Navigate from one view to another view in ios?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have tab bar with 4 options.
In the 1st tab, I have a button. When i click this button, I have to move from one view to another view in second tab bar.

the code I am currently using is (*where `shipVC` is the second tab's `viewController`*):

```
[shipVC.navigationController pushViewController:cartVC animated:NO];
```

So basically, When the button in the 1st tab `viewController` is pressed, I want to move from 'X' view to 'Y' view in the 2nd tab's `viewController`

Comment: [self.navigationController pushViewController:cartVC animated:NO ];

Comment: i am not navigating in the same view

Comment: provide more information, the question is vague and unclear (_right now_)

Comment: When an button in first Tab bar pressed,I have to move from 'X' view to 'Y' view in second tab bar

Comment: @Madhu : so actions in one `viewController` need to manifest changes in another (_unrelated?_) `viewController`? that can be done via `NSNotificationCenter` or by using the delegation pattern. (_both are easy_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick way to do this is by using `NSNotificationCenter` to post a notification when the button in the first tab's `viewController` is pressed.

### Steps:

1. in the 2nd tab's `viewController`'s `-viewDidLoad` method:

   - Add a notification observer and set a target selector method to it
2. in the 1st tab's `viewController`'s button method:

   - Post the notification

### Example:

Your 2nd tab's `viewController` class:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(doTheNavigation)
                                                name:@"AnyNameYouWantForNotification"
                                              object:nil];
}

-(void)doTheNavigation {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:cartVC animated:NO];
    //WARNING: don't just push, put a check  or else repeated click on the
    //button in the 1st tab will push cartVC again and again.
    //This will not only warrant a crash but look very ugly
}
```

---

Button method in the 1st tab's `viewController` class:

```
-(IBAction)someBtnClick:(UIButton *)sender {
    //...
    //you can use this to post a notification from anywhere now
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"AnyNameYouWantForNotification" 
                                                        object:nil];
    //...
}
```

---

### So...

- When the button in the 1st tab is clicked, the button action (*that I named `someBtnClick`*) will post a notification with the name `AnyNameYouWantForNotification`
- The 2nd tab (*should be already loaded and ready*) will be listening for a notification that has `AnyNameYouWantForNotification` as it's name.

  - When this notification is received, it will execute the linked selector method (*that I named `doTheNavigation`*)

Comment: @Madhu : you're welcome. notifications are easy and resourceful. apple docs are a good read as well: [link: NSNotificationCenter Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

check my answer

```
-(void)settabbar{

        UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[viewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewController1" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[viewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewController2" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        UIViewController *viewController3 = [[[viewController3 alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewController3" bundle:nil] autorelease];


        navControl1=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
        navControl2=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
        navControl3=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController3];

        navControl1.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8];
        navControl2.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        navControl3.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];

        self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
        self.tabBarController.delegate=self;
        self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navControl1,navControl2,navControl3, nil ];

        [[[[self.tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:2] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
        [[[[self.tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:@"view1"];
        [[[[self.tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:0] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab2.png"]];
        [[[[self.tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:1] setTitle:@"view2"];
        [[[[self.tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:1] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab11.png"]];
        [[[[self.tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:2] setTitle:@"ciew3"];
        [[[[self.tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:2] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab5.png"]];
        [[[[self.tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:3] setTitle:@"Maintain Customer"];
        [[[[self.tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:3] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab4.png"]];

        [self.tabBarController.tabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"trans.png"]];

        UIImage* tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
        [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];
        [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"trans.png"]];
    }

    -(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController*)viewController{

        NSLog(@"select : %d",tabBarController.tabBar.selectedItem.tag);

        if(self.tabBarController.tabBar.selectedItem.tag==0){
            [[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }else if(self.tabBarController.tabBar.selectedItem.tag==1){
            [[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }else if(self.tabBarController.tabBar.selectedItem.tag==2){
            [[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }else {
            [(UINavigationController*) viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }

        return YES;

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to also make application with Naigationcontroller in your appdelegate

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] ;


 HomeViewController *homeView = [[HomeViewController alloc]        initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:homeView animated:YES];
UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:homeView];

self.window.rootViewController = navController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

after that your navigationbar will appear in your  first viewcontroller then you can navigate.

Comment: i am not navigating in the same view

Comment: if you wan to navigate other Tab the its not possible fo that you need to use :    [tabController setSelectedIndex:1];

Comment: When i use this method [tabController setSelectedIndex:1]; Defaultly it is showing the last view which we have placed in our stack.But i want the my own screen to be loaded

Comment: when you click on bottun and then you want to goto second Tab then write this code in Button click action.